# Double Tap To Wake Up Android Device Programatically?

Tags: android

i want to make an android app that if user can Double tap the screen of the android screen  to wake it up this is the by default functionality of Google device or Android L.  i want to make like this anyone have idea about that.

http://www.theverge.com/2014/10/28/7082875/12-best-new-features-android-lollipop-nexus

Comment: its hardware functionality

Comment: @JeffyLazar is it possible or not ??

Comment: so that is what asked ...
what have you tried till now? where are you stuck ?
show us some code ?
post yout logcat..so that we can help you with the code

Comment: i'm just complete the screenOFF app but i want to add functionality like above but i didn't get any idea

Comment: you can do something like creating a transparent widget on homescreen and then handle the double tap or touch event

Comment: reached something ?!!